# cx_Freeze not correctly converting python program(s) into executable

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have the following files for a project in pygame:

```
> extras.py

> main.py

> settings.txt

# main.py imports extras.py
```

I am trying to convert into an executable using `cx_Freeze`.

My `setup.py` file is as follows

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable("main.py")]

setup(
    name = 'Pong',
    author = 'Ethan',
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "packages":["pygame", "sys", "random"],
            "include_files":["settings.txt"]
            }},
    executables = executables,
    version = "5.1.1"
)
```

It builds without errors but upon running the `exe` it launches a window then immediately closes. I have gotten a single python file to build but can't figure out how to do multiple.

Comment: It seems you have not placed the `extras.py`.

Comment: ok, but where do I place it, I tried putting it in both the `"include_files"` and adding `"include":["extras.py"],`, neither worked`

Comment: Try: `executables = [Executable("main.py"), Executable("extras.py")]`

Comment: that worked, thanks, yet I don't understand why you need to specify it as another executable.

Comment: also is there a way to mark this as solved, even if the answer was in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
executables = [Executable("main.py"), Executable("extras.py")]
```